# react-router 4 scroll restoration prevents native behaviour of anchor links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using this solution to restore the scroll on page change:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <ScrollToTop>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Main />
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </ScrollToTop>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

This is my `ScrollToTop` component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

class ScrollToTop extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop)
```

This works fine except for anchor links; in fact, it overrides the behaviour of anchor links and I cannot scroll to the desired section of the page. I know I could create a container and use it just in pages I want to use it; however, I would still have the same problem since the navigation to the same page could be triggering different behaviour (sometimes scrolling the window to top and sometimes scrolling to the anchor link). Is there a way to preserve the desired behaviour in either circumstance?

Comment: Check `window.location.hash` to see if the value is set in the `componentDidUpdate`. If so, don't scroll.

Comment: If you posted this as answer with the edited code I would accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the `window.location.hash` property to see if you are accessing an anchor link and then scroll to the top if you are not. Your code would look something like that:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

class ScrollToTop extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const hasLocationChanged = this.props.location !== prevProps.location;
    const urlHasHash = window.location.hash !== '';

    if (hasLocationChanged && !urlHasHash) {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return this.props.children;
  }
}

export default withRouter(ScrollToTop);
```